# How do I hide the PHP explode delimiter from submitted form results?

Tags: php, forms, explode, delimiter, nl2br

I have created a form which utilizes a .txt file to pull the names of the EMPLOYEES from and breaks them up in the SELECT form option using the PHP explode function.

```
<select name="FakeName" id="Fake-ID" aria-required="true" required>
 <option value=""></option>
  <?php
   $options=nl2br(file_get_contents("employees.txt"));
   $options=explode("<br />",$options);

   for($i=0;$i<count($options);$i++)
   {
    echo "<option value='".$options[$i]."'>".$options[$i]."</option>";
   }
 ?>
</select>
```

The .txt file appears as such:

```
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
ETC
```

Now this works in the form on the site and properly breaks it up and all looks fine. However, when the results are submitted into a SPREADSHEET (in this case a GOOGLE SPREADSHEET) the output includes the "break" and thus it goes into the spreadsheet in a format similar to:

```
Row 1: Name 1
Row 2:
       Name 2
Row 3:
       Name 3
Row 4:
       ETC
```

I am trying to figure out how to change the code or something so that the delimiter itself does not submit as part of the results. NOTE: Using any delimiter submits. I have tried "\" or ";" and it submits with results.

Comment: why are you exploding it by<br/>, is it a html document. Usually text document will \n or \r

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Because using /n or /r or any other physically seen delimiter was going into the spreadsheet as results. So I decided to use `<br />` as it was virtually unseen in the .txt file due to just going down a line and thus appeared to work in the results as unseen. It was not till today that I realize the results actually had a line break.

Comment: Are you writing something to the spreadsheet? I am confused.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar It is a form, and when it submits to the spreadsheet it includes the delimiter.

Comment: THere are no `<br/>` in the option values. You myst be adding them back in the code that processes the form. That's the code we need to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the line breaks with nl2br() and then removing the line breaks with explode(), try using the line break character '\r' or '\n' or '\r\n'.

```
<?php
    $options= file_get_contents("employees.txt");
    $options=explode("\n",$options);        // try \r as well.

    foreach ($options as $singleOption){
        echo "<option value='".$singleOption."'>".$singleOption."</option>";
    }

 ?>
```

This could also fix the issue if the problem was due to Google Spreadsheets reading the line breaks.

Comment: Alright it seems that `/n` did not work as it added a break after the string in the form results...which was better.

Then I attempted `/r` and it resulted in the original issue of the break before the string.

However, third time is a charm and `/r/n` seems to have worked perfectly and there is no longer any break on either side of the option string.

I really need to focus on learning my PHP more and understand what all that is. Thank you though.

Comment: Glad I could help. I think the issue was that the /r/n was added into the <option> field and as a result, Google Spreadsheets saw that and added the line break as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="FakeName" id="Fake-ID" aria-required="true" required>

<?php
$options=nl2br(file_get_contents("employees.txt"));
$options=explode("<br />",$options); 
foreach ($options as $item_array)
{
echo "<option value='".$item_array"'>".$item_array"</option>";
 }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Attempted this and not sure what it did differently, but it all ended with the same result with the spreadsheet still including the delimiter break.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different approach like read the file line by line instead of dealing with all this nl2br / explode stuff.

```
$fh = fopen("employees.txt", "r");
if ($fh) {
    while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) {
        $line = trim($line);
        echo "<option value='".$line."'>".$line."</option>";
    }
} else {
    // error opening the file, do something
}
```

Also maybe just doing a trim (remove whitespace from beginning/end of string) is your issue?

And maybe people are just misunderstanding what you mean by "submitting results to a spreadsheet" -- are you doing this with code? or a copy/paste from an HTML page into a spreadsheet? Maybe you can explain that in more detail. The delimiter for which you split the lines of the file shouldn't be displaying in the output anyway unless you have unexpected output for some other reason.

Comment: One of the other answers worked for me, but at some point I will have to try what you listed.

On another note the form submission process was handled by GOOGLE. I created a form on their system and then seriously edited it to fit into a webpage. Thus the form submits to a google form URL which places the responses in a spreadsheet.